# netty client performance/scalability: Multi-threaded write to one channel vs. multiple channels

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, scalability, throughput

I'm running into an issue I noticed with scalability when writing multi-threaded to one or multiple channels in netty 4.0.28. I could not find anything on SO about this topic. I found only "Hey, multithreading improves throughput" questions but mine is somehow the opposite of that.

In general, writing to one channel is faster than writing to multiple channels, and I do not have any idea, why this is, especially when waiting the write to complete.

The results I get are (writeAndFlush median, with warming and multiple test runs):

- single connection: 6.6M ops/sec without wait and about 60K ops/sec with await
- 4 connections: 5.1M ops/sec without wait and about 47K ops/sec with await
- I observed a performance increase when using Oio, performance decrease when using Nio

My setup:

- Nio Sockets with shared NioEventLoopGroup
- Between 2 and 4 writing threads (Event Loop group threads = 2 * writing threads)
- write small messages and flush after write
- For the test: No read and connections are not closed

My expectation:

- Writing on multiple connections is faster than writing on a single connection (not necessarily linear, but should be still better than on one connection)

**Bootstrap**

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(eventLoopGroup);
b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class); 
b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(NioSocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
    }
});

// Start the client.
ChannelFuture f = b.connect(socketAddress).await();
channel = f.channel();
```

**Write**

```
// non-blocking
channel.writeAndFlush(message, channel.voidPromise());
```

or

```
// blocking
channel.writeAndFlush(message).await();
```

The full code is available at https://gist.github.com/mp911de/7a3d7206931c8c4dc581

Comment: A very naive change using directly `PooledByteBufAllocator` and `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` scores 600K ops/sec.

Comment: 4.0 does not use `PooledByteBufAllocator` by default. Could you specify `ChannelOption.ALLOC` and try again?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just upgrade to 4.1.0.BetaX

Comment: A different allocator does not affect the results with 4.0. Version 4.1.0.Beta5 is some 30 - 40% slower than 4.0 without awaiting the promise and 15% slower with awaiting the promise. A single connection is still faster than distributing writes amongst multiple connections (tested all four combinations). Sockets transfer 1-2 MB/sec (according to the Yourkit profiler)

Comment: That's interesting. Care to file an issue with a reproducer, so we can try to understand what the problem is?

Comment: Done, find it at https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3919